# Displaying the sum of values within a given polygon

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mapping

I am using some sample data to try to figure out the best method to complete the desired task so that I can ensure all the proper data is transcribed in the coming weeks. I have hundreds of reports that include a proposed number of roads that may or may not have been constructed. There is little post-project reporting or much for ground-truthing on the part of compliance or enforcement agencies, so there is no linear spatial data associated with these proposed roads. All that we have is a general project location (point location), and the total proposed kilometers of road or trail. I would like to display the total proposed kilometers of roads, for each project that falls within a subsubdrainage (Polygon), or a given 10x10km grid (polygon).
I would like to calculate the sum of attributes from a point later that fall within an overlapping grid layer (polygons), to then display a gradient of proposed total kilometers of road within a given area.

[image]

I have tried working with spatial join in ArcMap to combine the grid layer with the point layer, but I was not able to find a means to calculate and display the sum roads.

After doing some research I found the Statistic by Category Tool in QGIS.
It looks like it could calculate what I want, and then I could potentially (?) join the results to the polygon grid and display as a gradient.

The issue is that when I tried to use the statistic by category tool the sum and range are not included in the results table. When I was doing my research it appeared as the two attributes were included in other people's results. I updated my QGIS from 3.6 to 3.12 but it did not make any difference. Am I missing something in order to obtain these results? 
[image]

Comment: Looking at your statistics by category table it appears that the column you were summarising (`id`?) is a string/text datatype - that's why instead of numeric aggregates (sum, median, stdev...) you have string-based aggregates (length of string). Try it out with a numeric field

Comment: Thanks, that resolved it.